# Access Methods of an Object stored in state with Zustand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, state, zustand

I am having an issue accessing methods of an object retrieved from state. What would be the correct way of storing an object, along with all of its methods in state so that they may be accessed later.

Store (store.jsx)

```
import create from "zustand";
import { persist } from "zustand/middleware";
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash";

const initialState = {
  user: undefined,
  profile: undefined,
}

let store = (set) => ({
  ...initialState,
  setUser: (user) => set((state) => ({ user: cloneDeep(user) })),
  setProfile: (profile) => set((state) => ({ profile: profile })),
  logout: () => {set(initialState)},
});
store = persist(store);
export const useUserStore = create(store);
```

Setting State (file2.jsx)

```
import { useUserStore } from "../../store";

const setUser = useUserStore((state) => state.setUser);

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

     //all properties and methods defined here
      setUser(user);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Accessing stored state (file2.jsx)

```
import { useUserStore } from "../../../store/userStore";

const user = useUserStore((state) => state.user);

//usage, no methods defined at this point.
user.updateEmail() <--- method is not defined
```

**Workaround / Correct Implementation??**
Access currentUser in [auth instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#properties).

Comment: maybe it’s me, but I don’t see `updateEmail` being defined anywhere. Are you sure that methods get serialized into the store as well?

Comment: updateEmail is a prop defined on this [firebase user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User) object. @Psi

Comment: have you checked if user is not undefined in subscriber in the useeffect and successfully stored in zustand?

Comment: and how do you know that firebase is even involved here?

Comment: Im authenticating a user with firebase auth and then [listening to user state changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) . Firebase auth is working correctly so thats not the issue. Issue is understanding how to properly store this user in order to access all its properties and methods. @Psi

Comment: @linusw No this is not wrapped around a condition as application relies on this user state ie if user is null certain routes are private.

Comment: @Josh I was asking for debug purposes only. Put a console.log(user) in subscriber and check if it is defined and has the updateEmail function available, then console or  check in react dev tools store snapshot when it is supposed to be ready. Until/if someone comes and pinpoints exact issue, at least you can hopefully find the link that chain breaks.

Comment: @linusw Values appear to be there in the component itself. For now I've done a workaround by access the current user via the [auth instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#properties).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are persisting data, you are working with JSON. The data gets written to (for example) local storage as JSON, and read back from it. Since functions cannot exist in JSON, they are getting lost in translation.

You can use the [`merge`](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data#merge) function to merge your current state with your persisted state, allowing you to construct a user object from the user JSON in local storage.

You havent given an example of what your user object is, but I'll assume it's a class. As such, your merge function could be something like:

```js
class User {
  email;
  constructor(email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
  static fromJson(user) {
    return new User(user.email);
  }
  updateEmail() {
    console.log("updating email");
  }
}


// ...
merge: (persistedState, currentState) => {
  currentState.user = User.fromJson(persistedState.user);
  return currentState;
},
```

Now, if we try to call the `user.updateEmail` function, we no longer get an error and we see that the function is successfully called.

```
<button onClick={() => userStore.user?.updateEmail()}>Update</button>
```

[image]